# impossible to UPDATE a TimeStamp field in c#

Tags: c#, sql, database, datetime, timestamp

I have fields in my TimeStamp database that I am trying to UPDATE with c# code. But when I UPDATE my table either the fields are null or they have a bad value, but when I UPDATE the float or string fields in my table it works. Here is my code for update :

```
public void UpdateConstante(DateTime HeureModificationDesConstente, DateTime HeurePompe, DateTime TempsArrosage, float? TemperatureMax, float? TemperatureMin, string FormeSignal, float? HumiditeMax, float? HumiditeMin)
    {

        this.connection.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd = this.connection.CreateCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE constantedelaserre SET HeureModificationDesConstante = @HeureModificationDesConstente, HeurePompe = @HeurePompe, TempsArrosage = @TempsArrosage, TemperatureMax = @TemperatureMax, TemperatureMin = @TemperatureMin, FormeSignal = @FormeSignal, HumiditeMax = @HumiditeMax, HumiditeMin = @HumiditeMin;";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HeureModificationDesConstante", DateTime.Now);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HeurePompe", HeurePompe);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TempsArrosage", TempsArrosage);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TemperatureMax", TemperatureMax);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TemperatureMin", TemperatureMin);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FormeSignal", FormeSignal);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HumiditeMax", HumiditeMax);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HumiditeMin", HumiditeMin);
```

Here is what I see on phpmyadmin :

[image: 1]

Can you help me, please?

Comment: an update query has also ways a where clause else it would update **all** row. C´Basically i think you want an INSERT not an UPDATE

Comment: 1. Do not use `AddWithValue` - it may guess types wrong. 2. "ToBinary()"? Really? What's the DB Column type for this? And as nbk said: Where is your "WHERE"?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so for the where if I'm not mistaken I don't need it because I have only one row in my table, and for the toBinary I forgot to delete it but it's just a test I did because it doesn't work. Here is the code without the toBinary :

Comment: @FlorianROBERT even if you have one row in your table, I would suggest you, that you use a WHERE condition. Because in the future you maybe need a second row, but youre not remembering this SQL Statement. So it is more like a error prevention.

Comment: You stated in one case that it was working and in another case that it is not. Please provide code, as well as, images for both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the MySQL Function **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()**

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE constantedelaserre SET HeureModificationDesConstante = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), HeurePompe = @HeurePompe, TempsArrosage = @TempsArrosage, TemperatureMax = @TemperatureMax, TemperatureMin = @TemperatureMin, FormeSignal = @FormeSignal, HumiditeMax = @HumiditeMax, HumiditeMin = @HumiditeMin;";
```